# storing user's dropdown value in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I have the code below that creates a dropdown menu (ignore the single quotes). The dropdown looks like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button) on my end.

undefined the logging output here. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `@click` event on a wrong element..
your @ckick events should be added to `<a>` tags, so you could pass a `team_member.email` directly to your method.

```
<div v-if="active" class="dropdown-content">
  <a v-for="team_member in org_team_members"
    :key="team_member.email"
    @click="selectUsersInOrganization(team_member.email)>
    {{ team_member.name }}
  </a>
</div>
```

and the method should be:

```
selectUsersInOrganization(memberEmail) {
 this.email = memberEmail
 console.log(memberEmail)
}
```

p.s. if you would need more then just email, you could pass an entire `team_member` object like:
`@click="selectUsersInOrganization(team_member)`

so your method could have access to other members's properties

```
selectUsersInOrganization(member) {
 this.email = member.email
 this.name = member.name
 console.log(member)
}
```